# gear icon missing unity panel in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, themes, icons

i lost the gear icon in Unity panel while trying to change icon themes. the icon appears in ubuntu-mono-light and in some added themes. i reinstalled ubuntu desktop and unity but no success. is it an installation issue?is there any way to edit the panel to suit with icon size?

Answer (score 0):

Choose `radiance theme` in appearance and restart your pc.

Comment: it worked, now the problem is that the icon is visible only with very few icon themes.

Comment: if it works,plz select my answer as correct one.

Comment: remove `Myunity` if it was already installed,then change the theme to radiance and restart your pc.

Comment: thank you. i changed to radiance,icon theme. only ubuntu-mono icon theme brings back the gear. no other themes work. i am unable to customize the icon theme.i did not install myunity.